# how to request a service present in different package

Tags: ros, package, rosservice

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to call a service present in  package B (Python) from package A (c++).

When i run the code it says unable to find the header file (say packageB/service.h)
If i call a service present in Package A then its working fine.

Basically the question is how to request a service present in different package which is implemented in python.

I included the package dependencies in package.xml. Still no result..

Any idea what is wrong ??

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/73027/how-to-request-a-service-present-in-different-package/) by [kk](https://answers.ros.org/users/5289/kk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 225 on 2013-08-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-08-15**:
please provide more information on what you are doing and what's going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

thank you for the comment. Actually i fixed the issue. I had forgot to include the service definition.

---

Originally posted by [kk](https://answers.ros.org/users/5289/kk/) with karma: 225 on 2013-08-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1